# How do I align child elements within a bootstrap row across the middle of the horizontal axis?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I'm creating a side nav bar with a number of different `mat-list-item` elements that the user can click. I want these list items to have their icon and name aligned across the middle of the horizontal axis. How do I do this?

I've tried using justify content and align items and neither of them seem to work.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center ">
    <a mat-list-item  class="color-white drawer-list-item flex">
        <div class="col-6 h-100">
            <mat-icon class="icon">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 h-100">
            <span>{{name}}</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to add `justify-content-center align-items-center` to the `<a mat-list-item` element

Answer (score 0):

It [should be](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/) `d-flex`, not `flex`:

https://codepen.io/etrain/pen/BZdYwa

[image]